# Double Sided Linen Paper

Tags: print-design

I am printing out a brochure design that will be on [double sided linen paper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001B0E6P8) (pictured below):

[image: paper]

However, the linen texture is definitely more pronounced on one side over the other.  I have asked around at a few paper suppliers and nobody seems to have a solid answer for me - is there such a thing as double sided linen paper for printing?

Comment: There appears to be [plenty of it about](http://www.bing.com/search?q=double+sided+linen+paper&go=Submit&qs=ds&form=QBLH), but whether it bears the appropriate quality on both sides, who can say without a sample? You can ask [paper merchants](http://www.bing.com/search?q=paper+merchants+new+york&go=Submit&qs=ds&form=QBRE) for samples, though, and they will send them.

Comment: I expect that there are laminated sheets so as to have a full texture on both sides, but this can affect folding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The texture you're talking about comes from the screen on which the wet paper slurry is poured, allowing the majority of the water to drain away. It comes in two basic flavours: ***laid*** (most of the wires in the screen go only one direction, usually horizontally across the page, with only a few wires going the other direction) or ***wove*** (more like window screening). The rest of the process involves squashing the formed sheet of paper flat, removing that screen texture to one degree or another. It's not something that's impressed in the paper *after* it's a sheet.

The only standard papers that have a definite texture and more-or-less the same texture on both sides are *rough* and *cold pressed* heavy papers, such as you'd use for watercolours. That texture comes from felt blankets used in the wet squeezing process, and is quite irregular and lumpy rather than the regular texture of a laid or wove screen.

You can get decorative craft and cover papers that have textures on both sides, but they tend not to be white-ish and not terribly printer-friendly.

Comment: The reason it is more pronounced on one side, though, is because the paper pulp only directly contacts the screen on the one side.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of shopping at a place like Officemax / Amazon if you want something quality and specific then go to a higher end paper company like [French Paper](http://www.frenchpaper.com/custom-manufacturing) or [Neenah Paper](http://www.neenahpaper.com).

If they don't have what you're looking for they can probably help you find it or craft it for you. An alternative is also looking at a high end print shop like [Mama's Sauce](http://mamas-sauce.com) that can do [Duplexed and Triplexed paper](http://mamas-sauce.com/design-wise#710).